# How to pick repeatable date in Android?

Tags: android, datepicker

I would like to display picker component that will pick a day and month that should be repeated.

In a result user could get a repeatable data:

eg. "Repeat fourth day of month every month"

or "Repeat first day of month every two months"

Is there any standard UI component in Android that could be capable of allowing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a [DatePicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html) with the mindate and the maxDate set to the specific month you want?

I guess alternatively you could also hide the year Spinner.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The documentation for a DatePickerDialog is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html). If you want to embed that into a fragment, you can find a basic example in [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html) part of the documentation.